# What does "OSSP" stand for in the PostgreSQL's "ossp-uuid" extension?

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL has a module named `ossp-uuid`, which provides the functions to generate UUIDs. What does "OSSP" stand for?

Comment: As a side note: starting with Postgres 13 you might not need the module any longer, as a [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html) to generate UUIDs has be integrated into the core:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OSSP is an abbreviation of the non-profit project name. It stands for "Open Source Software project".

Citing from the [OSSP official site](http://www.ossp.org/),

> OSSP is a fully non-profit Open Source Software project, founded by Ralf S. Engelschall in 1998. Thomas Lotterer joined in 2001. The goal is the implementation of high-quality Unix software components, ranging from networking, multi-threading and algorithmic libraries to networking servers and development tools.

The [`uuid-ossp` module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/uuid-ossp.html) of PostgreSQL depends on the UUID library developed by OSSP. So it is called `uuid-ossp`.